# MySQL Case Statement for proper bucketing

Tags: mysql, case

reposting this question as I am still struggling to find the right solution.

I was able to isolate the 'OA' only scenarios and flag them appropriately as NA. However I am having trouble isolating the 'I' only events as well as properly aging the EquipID's that have both I and OA events.

This is the logic I am using for aging right now and it works great for 'I' only events, but properly isolating the 'I' and 'OA' EquipID's and then getting the difference between the two dates is eluding me.

`datediff(curdate(),concat(left(eventDateTime,4),'-',mid(eventDateTime,5,2),'-',mid(eventDateTime,7,2))) as age_in_depot`

I tried grouping by the EquipID but of course that gives me only one eventDateTime result and it is always the first result, which in the case of an 'I' and 'OA' it's only the 'I' eventDateTime.

I also have logic to identify the 'I' and 'OA' events, but this only works correctly if I am intending on grouping the EquipmentID's together to one line, which noted above, drops the 2nd eventDateTime entry needed to properly age these EquipID's.

`GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT StatusCD) as StatusCD`

[image: Data from query]

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. Once I have this 'I' only event flagged and aging I can finally finish out this dashboard I am building for our team.

Thank you in advance.

J

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just pinging you on this since you helped us sort it out the last time pretty quickly. Thanks in advance if you take a look at this.

Comment: Are we supposed to understand what `I` and `OA` represent?

Comment: If you want to keep all the rows but also show the concatenated statuses, you can do that by joining your table with a subquery that uses `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: 'I' would be 'In' warehouse, 'OA' would be 'Out of warehouse.' The 'OA' only event's do not have an 'I' event because they are EquipID's that had their 'In Warehouse' happen before we started receiving an EDI file from a new client. Those that have an 'I' only or 'I' and 'OA' are on the most recent EDI file.

Comment: Do not try to add words to unknown/non-listed question. Post the task from the same beginning. Add sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, ~10 rows enough) and show desired output for this data strictly (not "must look like") with detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot the table so you get the in and out dates into separate columns for the same `EquipID`. Then you can subtract them, and apply appropriate defaults for the missing dates.

```
SELECT EquipID, InDate, OutDate, StatusCD_N,
    CASE WHEN InDate AND OutDate THEN DATEDIFF(OutDate, InDate)
         WHEN InDate THEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), InDate)
         ELSE 'N/A' -- only OutDate
    END AS AgeInDepot
FROM (
    SELECT EquipID, GROUP_CONCAT(StatusCD) AS StatsuCD_N,
        MAX(IF(StatusCD = 'I', DATE(STR_TO_DATE(eventDateTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i')), NULL) AS InDate,
        MAX(IF(StatusCD = 'OA', DATE(STR_TO_DATE(eventDateTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i')), NULL) AS OutDate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY EquipID
) AS x
```

Comment: This is what I did actually, except I isolated 'I' with a MIN, and 'OA' with a MAX date within a DATEDIFF() and it worked perfectly.

Comment: If there's at most one `I` and `OA` row for each equipment ID, it shouldn't matter. I didn't know how you wanted to deal with multiple rows.